# How to solve this system of three coupled differential equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, partial-derivative, differential

I need to integrate this system of partial derivatives:

\begin{align}
x' - y' + z = 0 \\
y' - z' + x = 0 \\
z' - x' + y = 0
\end{align}

Comment: No pictures please.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to find the characteristic equation but nothing

Comment: @MădălinaPascu: What do you mean partial derivatives? Is it $$x' - y' + z = 0 \\ y' - z' + x = 0 \\ z' - x' + y = 0$$

Comment: I need to integrate that system

Comment: Maybe you can right click on the MathJax, copy what I wrote and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess the form:  $x(t) = a_x \cos(b_x t) + c_x \sin (d_x t)$ and likewise for $y(t)$ and $z(t)$.  Perform your differentiation and equate coefficients to find:

$$x(t) = \sqrt{3} \left(c_2-2 c_1\right) \sin \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+3
   c_2 \cos \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

$$y(t) = \sqrt{3} \left(c_1-2 c_2\right) \sin \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-3
   c_1 \cos \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$

$$z(t) = \sqrt{3} \left(c_1+c_2\right) \sin \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+3
   \left(c_1-c_2\right) \cos \left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$